# Does creating an index on a text column make search costlier?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, architecture, sql-server-2014

Does having a string column as the primary key instead of an integer column adversely affect search times and/or insertion times?

**Scenarios**

a. A common scenario for any application is to make this query every time someone creates a new user account:

*Does that user name already exist or is it taken by someone else?*

b. And when a person logs in, another query that looks up the user name is required to be made like so:

*Does a row with that `UserName` exist in the `User` table?*

c. Similarly, when a user says they've forgotten their password, we need to search based on their email.

*Does a row with that `Email` exist in the `User` table?*

d. It is only in the case of linking up the `User` table with other user related tables such as `UserRole`, `UserClaim`, etc. that we may need to join them based on an integer `Id` like so:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM User, UserClaim
  WHERE User.Id = UserClaim.UserId;
```

**Having an Integer as the Primary Key vs. Having a String as the Primary Key**

Till now, I've always just had a user table with an integer primary key (and clustered index thereon), like so:

```
User
-----
Id int primary key identity(1, 1),
UserName nvarchar(50) not null,
Email nvarchar(100) not null,
PasswordHash nvarchar(32) not null
```

However, now contemplating over the use-cases I described above, I am wondering if it is more fruitful to instead completely eliminate the integer primary key and instead make one of the `UserName` or `Email` field as the primary key like so:

```
User
-----
UserName nvarchar(50) primary key,
Email nvarchar(100) not null,
PasswordHash nvarchar(32) not null
```

That would create a clustered index on the `UserName` field probably speeding up queries in scenarios **a** and **b** listed above, but I am not sure of the impact scenarios **c** and **d** because that would depend on the speed or comparing integers with speed of comparing indices based on a string column.

**Questions**

However, that leaves me with a few lose ends I need to tie up before I can commit on this design:

1. Does making a clustered index on a text field like the above have any performance implications? How does it effect insertion times? Search times?

   I would imagine creating an index on an integer is faster than on a string?
2. We can have only one clustered index. If I allow my users to login using either a user name or email, anyone they like, then I am going to have to make searches on both the `UserName` and `Email` fields just as frequently. How do I manage that? Should I make a non-clustered index on the `Email` field?
3. Would having a string column as the primary key have an impact on performance of the joins I do with other link tables like so:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM User, UserRole
   WHERE User.UserName = UserRole.UserName;
   ```
4. Considering #3, it looks like I should just keep the integer `Id` column in the `User` table and create a non-clustered index each on the `UserName` and `Email` columns?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to never use email as a primary key. Why? Because people change their email addresses. Now that doesn't mean it can't be the clustered index of a table. And when discussing things like performance words like "probably" need to be avoided. Don't guess, put together some test tables and find out. You also should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins I am voting to close this as opinion based but it is also too broad.

Comment: @SeanLange People actually change their email addresses? Like, how? You mean they could stop using an email they had and get a new one in addition to the old one, right? Or, can someone abandon an email address and that email be allotted to someone else?

Comment: Are serious? Are you saying you have had the same email since you got your first one? What happens when somebody's name changes? Do they have to use their old email address because your system can't handle changing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does making a clustered index on a text field like the above have any
>   performance implications? How does it affect insertion times? Search
>   times?

- Every row of every non-clustered index will contain the clustered index key as rowkey. `INT = 4 bytes`, your unicode string column `Email` can potentially occupy `NVARCHAR(100) = up to 200 bytes`.
- Clustered indexes are good for range scans. Range scan on email addresses are hardly expected.
- An identity-based clustered index is an of warranty close to zero fragmentation and fast inserts, due to an absence of page splits

> We can have only one clustered index. If I allow my users to login
>   using either a user name or email, anyone they like, then I am going
>   to have to make searches on both the UserName and Email fields just as
>   frequently. How do I manage that? Should I make a non-clustered index
>   on the Email field?

Yes, if you will decide to make a unique clustered index on `UserName`, you will want to have another nonclustered index on `Email`. If a user will search by `Email` column, column username will be part of such index automatically (because of the reason explained in a point above) and such index will be covered.

> Would having a string column as the primary key have an impact on
>   performance of the joins

A clustered index on `UserName` column is optimal for such joins, because it will keep data preordered, so on large datasets instead `HASH` joins are more likely to be replaced by `MERGE` joins

> Considering #3, it looks like I should just keep the integer Id column
>   in the User table and create a non-clustered index each on the
>   UserName and Email columns?

It very much depends on your workload. If you have to frequently join that table on a column `UserName`, it can be that clustered index on such column will work for you. In that case, you can make a non-clustered unique index on a field `Email` and keep a primary key on `ID` but make it non-clustered also

(This post is based pretty much on personal opinion)

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing your suggestions. They have helped me.